# Sliding Menu and something like that in API 8

Tags: android

Android API 11 and over has a few new things such as sliding content - sliding menu etc. However, some applications made it in API 8. For instance, [EventBrite](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eventbrite.attendee&hl=tr&ei=djxsUdPVO6T07Abls4DoAw&usg=AFQjCNE721CN3ZxHL0uJSGYI0kczZa15cQ&sig2=GtPnEcAcYzQTxVOn3wze9A&bvm=bv.45175338,d.ZGU) made whatever I want. How do I do the same thing in API 8 (2.2 and over)?

Comment: What is a "sliding content-menu"?

Comment: There is a library on github that has implemented a SlidingMenu which makes it avaialbe to API levels prior to 11. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: I meant sliding content or sliding menu etc.

Comment: What does "sliding content" or "sliding menu" mean? Since you claim that these things are in API Level 11, please feel to point out relevant Java classes in the SDK. I see nothing in EventBrite's screenshots that look "sliding" other than a `ListView` (API Level 1) and possibly a `ViewPager` (Android Support package, API Level 4+).

Comment: @FoamyGuy gave the link that I certainly supposed to find. Thank you.

Comment: There are no current API's in the SDK currently to support a "Sliding Menu" such as the one in Facebook or Spotify. as pointed out by @FoamyGuy the most popular "Sliding Menu" library currently is the one by jfeinstein on Github.